# insert zk log check in and out to one row in database

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, zkteco

I am retrieving data from ZK attendance device using [zkteco-sdk-php](https://github.com/nurkarim/zkteco-sdk-php).

The out come is like this

| UID | ID | NAME | STATE | DATE | TIME | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 275 | Employ1 | Fingerprint | 19-06-2021 | 08:14:16 | Check-in |
| 55 | 275 | Employ1 | Fingerprint | 19-06-2021 | 11:15:20 | Check-out |

*and all the data is not sorted by user its sorted by the first finger print attendance so the log is mixed up with different users and different type of attendance

I want to insert the retrieved data to database the issue is the data is being retrieved
each log (check in OR check out) as a single row
I want to insert the same day (check in && check out for the same user in the same row )

this is what I am aiming for

| ID | user ID | Check-in | Check-out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 275 | 19-06-2021 08:14:16 | 19-06-2021 11:15:20 |

this is the code for retrieving the data from zk

```
                    $attendance = $zk->getAttendance();
                    if (count($attendance) > 0) {
                        $attendance = array_reverse($attendance, true);
                        sleep(1);
                        foreach ($attendance as $attItem) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo($attItem['uid']); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($attItem['id']); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo(isset($users[$attItem['id']]) ? $users[$attItem['id']]['name'] : $attItem['id']); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo(ZK\Util::getAttState($attItem['state'])); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($attItem['timestamp']))); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo(date("H:i:s", strtotime($attItem['timestamp']))); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo(ZK\Util::getAttType($attItem['type'])); ?></td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: Is a check-in row for the user always followed directly by a checkout row for the same user in the data? Or can the order be different sometimes? Also what is the data structure in the table you are targeting? There is a bit of important info missing from your question.

Comment: I edited the question I hope its more clear thx alot

Comment: Is `UUID` field is unique field fro session? (In other words only one check-in and one check-out with same UUID)?

Comment: The date column is not `DATE` datatype. I see the retrieval code for date is `(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($attItem['timestamp']))`.. Can it be `"Y-m-d"` instead?

Comment: We're using ZK as well but it seems our retrieval code is not the same. Most of the fields are similar but in our retrieval, we don't have column `type` to differentiate between `check-in` and `check-out` and we record date+time as `datetime` datatype instead of separating it. I think you're missing some important details in your question; for example how many `check-in` and `check-out` for someone in a day? If this is an attendance record for employee, I think an employee should at least have 4 records in a day (in, rest-out, rest-in, out) right?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev UUID is the user id

Comment: @FaNo_FN i think its because the device is different, about the check in and out i only have two in and out

Comment: I see. How about the date? The current date data that you show is not according to the date datatype in MySQL which is `YYYY-MM-DD`. What is the current datatype? Maybe you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68053465/edit)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SELECT
   t1.ID,
   t1.UserID,
   ADDTIME(CONVERT(t1.`date`, DATETIME), t1.`time`) as "Check-in",
   ADDTIME(CONVERT(t2.`date`, DATETIME), t2.`time`) as "Check-out"
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.ID=t1.ID 
                  and t2.UserID=t1.UserID
                  and t2.Type = 'Check-out'
WHERE 
   ID = 55
   and UserID = 275
   and Type = 'Check-in'
```

NOTE: You need to replace `table` with the correct table name.

Different examples on how to use this SQL query in PHP can be found in a lot of places, like: [Google: how to query MySQL from PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+query+MySQL+from+PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You should to store logs "as is" - separate rows to check-in and check-out and  on select join two rows by `UUID` and `ID`:

```
select 
    log_in.uuid,
    log_in.id,
    log_in.name,
    log_in.state,
    log_in.event_time as log_in_time,
    log_out.event_time as log_out_time
from zk_log log_in
join zk_log log_out on log_in.uuid = log_out.uuid and log_in.id = log_out.id
where log_in.event_type = 'check-in' and log_out.event_type = 'check-out';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved like this:

```
SELECT UID,
       ID,
       CONCAT(date,' ',MIN(time)) AS Check_in,
       CONCAT(date,' ',MAX(time)) AS Check_out
FROM attendance
GROUP BY date, UID, ID;
```

But I have to address that the `date` data in your example is not standard MySQL `DATE` datatype and if the destination table that you want to insert to have structure like:

```
destination_table 
(UID INT, 
ID INT,
Check_in DATETIME,  <--- this datatype
Check_out DATETIME); <---
```

the insert will not be successful and will return an error:

> Incorrect datetime value: '19-06-2021 08:14:16' for column 'Check_in' at row 1

Otherwise, if the `destination_table` datatype is `VARCHAR()`, it won't have problem inserting. However, I highly encourage using the standard format **at least** on the destination table. So if the source table really stores date as `VARCHAR()` and the destination table is using `DATETIME` datatype, you'll need `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table
SELECT UID,
       ID,
       CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),' ',MIN(time)) AS Check_in,
       CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y'),' ',MAX(time)) AS Check_out
FROM attendance
GROUP BY date, UID, ID;
```

[Here's a demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96de3d907cdd1b2685bb686cc8ff2b8a)